# Apache rewrite rule that ignores query/parameters, always redirects based on path

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that will ignore any additional URL query/parameters and just redirect based on the path.

My company has a Wifi Hotspot service that does some DNS routing trick to force people to login before they can use it.  Unfortunately when folks get disconnected from the WiFi and dropped back to their normal cell data service sometimes a URL request is still sent to our host, and it shows up as:

```
www.ourwebsite.com/login?dst=http://www.google.com/m?client=ms-android-verizon&source=android-home
```

I already wrote a set of rules to take care of base paths of /login and /login/ to redirect to our homepage,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/login/\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)login/?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/login\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)login?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but I am having trouble coming up with an appropriate string to ALWAYS redirect based souly on the path, and ignore any query parameters that may or may not come after.

Any help would be appreciate!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, something like this should do it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login    /?   [R=301,L]
```

This rule-set will redirect to root as long as the incoming URL is something like:

`http://www.ourwebsite.com/login?any_query`

Answer (score 1):

From Apache 2.4.0 on you can apply the `QSD`-flag to the rule.

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string to be discarded.
>   -- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd

When using this flag for earlier Apache versions you'll cause an `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: This is a great solution if you are using Apache 2.4 or later.